# Gaining access to system drive

Tags: java, operating-system, file-permissions, copy-paste, permission-denied

**How do I gain access to the System Drive(I mean the root).**
I need this a s I would have to copy one of the exe file that is required for my program to run to be copied into the System Drive. *I do this by copying an exe file that is inside my program (jar) to the System Drive, In my case as(C:/file.exe).*
This is because it does some jobs like manipulating the registry or like making the computer sleep. 
I also had to do tasks like shutting down the computer but I did that using the shutdown.exe , but I cannot find any for sleeping the computer or turning off the monitor
Whenever I try to do this the error I get is either (Access Denied) or (File not found).
I am using netbeans... In the jar create it is in : jar name.jar\program name\file.exe And in the java file(ie in the src it is in) : H:\src\program name\file.exe

I would be satisfied with an alternative to do the certain tasks.

Comment: As you have tagged your question with _java_ , I suppose you are doing this from within a java application. Please provide us your code and where this .exe file is located in the structure of your jar file.

Comment: I am using netbeans... In the jar create it is in : jar name.jar\program name\file.exe                                                          And in the java file(ie in the src it is in) : H:\src\MotionSenser\file.exe

Comment: Hard coding the path to your file is a very bad idea and probably the cause of your errors. The answer of @Kwebble is a good suggestion, as it makes the location of your file relative to the root of the jar. But I would really like to see your java code or I can not help you any further.

Answer (score 1):

I would try to put the file in the jar as a resource, retrieve an inputstream to it with [Class.getResourceAsStream()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResourceAsStream%28java.lang.String%29) and write the stream to a File.

BTW, interesting idea to include .exe as resource in jar. But they only run on Windows, so how provide the same functions on other operating systems?

Comment: Did you check the documentation of the exception that is thrown for possible causes? And what is the exception?

Comment: Yea it was a problem with copying I made it out.